# How to consolidate these almost identical C functions?

Tags: c, templates

The C functions below are identical to each other except for only having different prototypes.  Is there any neat way to consolidate them somehow?

```c
    /* convert strings into numbers within range */
    int ciphart_str2size_t(
        char f, const char *s, size_t min, size_t max, size_t *out
    ) {
        *out = 0;
        int i, num;
        for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++) {
            num = s[i] - '0';
            if (*out > (max - max % 10)/ 10 - num + max % 10) {
                ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is larger than maximum '%zu'", f, s, max);
                return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
            }
            *out *= 10;
            *out += num;
        }
        if (s[i] != '\0') {
            ciphart_err("'-%c %s' contains illegal symbol '%c'", f, s, s[i]);
            return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
        }
        if (*out < min) {
            ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is smaller than minimum '%zu'", f, s, min);
            return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
        }
        return RETURN_OK;
    }

    int ciphart_str2uint64_t(
        char f, const char *s, uint64_t min, uint64_t max, uint64_t *out
    ) {
        *out = 0;
        int i, num;
        for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++) {
            num = s[i] - '0';
            if (*out > (max - max % 10)/ 10 - num + max % 10) {
                ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is larger than maximum '%zu'", f, s, max);
                return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
            }
            *out *= 10;
            *out += num;
        }
        if (s[i] != '\0') {
            ciphart_err("'-%c %s' contains illegal symbol '%c'", f, s, s[i]);
            return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
        }
        if (*out < min) {
            ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is smaller than minimum '%zu'", f, s, min);
            return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
        }
        return RETURN_OK;
    }
```

I am also going to add more variants of it, for `int` for example.  Hence I think consolidation would help reduce expected bugs in my code.

I added `templates` as a tag since I think this is about the template concept.  But answers could be with any other method than templates.  I just think people who watch templates might be interested in commenting about this.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `uint64_t` and `size_t` aren't the same type.

Comment: Isn't `(max - max % 10)/ 10` the same as `max/10` for integers?

Comment: If performance isn't critical, you could save code by implementing a version for `uintmax_t` and making the other functions call that one. (They would need a temporary variable of type `uintmax_t` to be copied to their `*out`.)

Comment: @dbush I wouldn't be surprised at all. Some MCUs have really weird sizes in this regard.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Turns out that while largest value stored in `size_t` cannot exceed `uintmax_t`, there is no guarantee that `sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(uintmax_t)` as per the standard.  E.g. an implementation may use padding.  (Source: some smart people in ##c in freenode).

Comment: @caveman Are the sizes of the types relevant? It's the numeric ranges that matter.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Let `uintmax_t x; size_t y;`.  Suppose I do `(size_t) x = y`.  Also suppose that `sizeof (uintmax_t) < sizeof (size_t)`.  Then, won't this result into writing beyond the boundary of `x`'s memory?  Hence UB?

Comment: @caveman I'm not sure what you mean by `(size_t) x = y`. Do you mean `*(size_t)&x = y;`? Yes, that would write beyond `x`'s memory if `sizeof(uintmax_t) < sizeof(size_t)` (as well as being an invalid thing to do generally). That's why the wrapper functions need an intermediate variable such as `uintmax_t vout;` and pass `&vout` to the wrapped (`uintmax_t`) version of the function in place of their own `out` pointer parameter, then do `*out = vout;` afterwards. (The value of `vout` will be between `min` and `max` which are the same type as `*out` so will be in range.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a macro to template the function definition:

```
#define DEFINE_CIPHART_STR2(type)                                              \
int ciphart_str2##type(char f, const char *s, type min, type max, type *out)   \
{                                                                              \
   /* lots */                                                                  \
   /* of   */                                                                  \
   /* code */                                                                  \
   /* here */                                                                  \
   return RETURN_OK;                                                           \
}
```

Then call the macro to define the functions from the template:

```
DEFINE_CIPHART_STR2(size_t)
DEFINE_CIPHART_STR2(uint64_t)
```

**EDIT 1:** Since you are using `printf` format specifiers in the functions, you will probably need to also pass the part of the format specifier as a separate parameter:

```
#define DEFINE_CIPHART_STR2(type, pri)                                         \
int ciphart_str2##type(char f, const char *s, type min, type max, type *out)   \
{                                                                              \
   /* lots */                                                                  \
   /* of   */                                                                  \
   /* code */                                                                  \
   ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is larger than maximum '%" pri "'", f, s, max);       \
   /* here */                                                                  \
   return RETURN_OK;                                                           \
}
```

```
DEFINE_CIPHART_STR2(size_t, "zu")
DEFINE_CIPHART_STR2(uint64_t, PRIu64)
```

(`PRIu64` is a macro defined by `#include <inttypes.h>`.)

An alternative is to cast the values being printed to match the specifiers.

---

To save code space in the executable, rather than defining several large, nearly identical functions, you could define one function that works for the largest unsigned type, and define small, wrapper functions for each of the smaller unsigned types.

Example function for the largest unsigned type:

```
int ciphart_str2uintmax_t(char f, const char *s, uintmax_t min, uintmax_t max, uintmax_t *out)
{
    /* lots */
    /* of   */
    /* code */
    /* here */
    return RETURN_OK;
}
```

Example wrapper function for smaller unsigned type:

```
int int ciphart_str2size_t(char f, const char *s, size_t min, size_t max, size_t *out)
{
    uintmax_t vout;
    int ret = ciphart_str2uintmax_t(f, s, min, max, &vout);

    *out = vout;
    return ret;
}
```

A template macro could be used to define these wrapper functions (not the wrapped function) but since they are quite small, it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: EDIT: I added a variant of the template macro to also pass the format specifier that matches the type.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return *two* values: an error code and an "output" value.

There are a number of ways to achieve this.

Note that `uint64_t` is [probably] larger than `size_t` [or the reverse]. Pick one. Or define a type that *is* larger than all of them.

---

Make the final argument an `int *` to accept the return code. It's an `int` in both of your functions. And, change the return to be the `out` value:

```
#define RETURN(code_) \
    do { \
        *err = code_; \
        return out; \
    } while (0)

/* convert strings into numbers within range */
uint64_t
ciphart_common(char f, const char *s, size_t min, size_t max, int *err)
{
    int i, num;

    out = 0;

    for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; i++) {
        num = s[i] - '0';
        if (out > (max - max % 10) / 10 - num + max % 10) {
            ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is larger than maximum '%zu'", f, s, max);
            RETURN(RETURN_FAIL_ARGS);
        }
        out *= 10;
        out += num;
    }

    if (s[i] != '\0') {
        ciphart_err("'-%c %s' contains illegal symbol '%c'", f, s, s[i]);
        RETURN(RETURN_FAIL_ARGS);
    }

    if (out < min) {
        ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is smaller than minimum '%zu'", f, s, min);
        RETURN(RETURN_FAIL_ARGS);
    }

    return RETURN(RETURN_OK);
}
```

---

With the number of args you have (e.g. 5), I sometimes like to create a `struct` that contains the parameters.

This has the advantage that if you have several functions that need to operate on these values, it saves a bunch of stack push/pop.

Also, you can have *many* return values.

```
struct param {
    char f;
    const char *s;
    size_t min;
    size_t max;

    int err;
    uint64_t out;
}

/* convert strings into numbers within range */
int
ciphart_common(struct param *p)
{
    int num;
    const char *s = p->s;
    size_t max = p->max;

    p->out = 0;

    for (;  (*s >= '0') && (*s <= '9');  ++s) {
        num = *s - '0';

        if (p->out > (max - max % 10) / 10 - num + max % 10) {
            ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is larger than maximum '%zu'",
                p->f, p->s, max);
            return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
        }

        p->out *= 10;
        p->out += num;
    }

    if (*s != '\0') {
        ciphart_err("'-%c %s' contains illegal symbol '%c'",
            p->f, p->s, *s);
        return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
    }

    if (p->out < p->min) {
        ciphart_err("'-%c %s' is smaller than minimum '%zu'",
            p->f, p->s, p->min);
        return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS;
    }

    return RETURN_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the template as a macro:

```
#define ciphart_generic_err(Fmt, F, S, T) _Generic( \
    (T), \
    char                  : ciphart_err(Fmt " '%c'",   F, S, T), \
    int                   : ciphart_err(Fmt " '%i'",   F, S, T), \
    unsigned int          : ciphart_err(Fmt " '%u'",   F, S, T), \
    long int              : ciphart_err(Fmt " '%li'",  F, S, T), \
    unsigned long int     : ciphart_err(Fmt " '%lu'",  F, S, T), \
    long long int         : ciphart_err(Fmt " '%lli'", F, S, T), \
    unsigned long long int: ciphart_err(Fmt " '%llu'", F, S, T)  \
)

#define ciphart_str_convert_impl(F, S, Min, Max, Out) \
do { \
    *Out = 0; \
    int i, num; \
    for (i = 0; S[i] >= '0' && S[i] <= '9'; i++) { \
        num = S[i] - '0'; \
        if (*Out > (Max - Max % 10)/ 10 - num + Max % 10) { \
            ciphart_generic_err("'-%c %s' is larger than maximum", F, S, Max); \
            return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS; \
        } \
        *Out *= 10; \
        *Out += num; \
    } \
    if (S[i] != '\0') { \
        ciphart_generic_err("'-%c %s' contains illegal symbol", F, S, S[i]); \
        return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS; \
    } \
    if (*Out < Min) { \
        ciphart_generic_err("'-%c %s' is smaller than minimum", F, S, Min); \
        return RETURN_FAIL_ARGS; \
    } \
    return RETURN_OK; \
} while (0)
```

and then define your different implementations.

```
int ciphart_str2size_t(
    char f, const char *s, size_t min, size_t max, size_t *out
){
    ciphart_str_convert_impl(f, s, min, max, out);
}

int ciphart_str2uint64_t(
    char f, const char *s, uint64_t min, uint64_t max, uint64_t *out
){
    ciphart_str_convert_impl(f, s, min, max, out);
}

// ... (any other proto)
```

Comment: How should the function in the macro look like to be type agnostic?

Comment: Yes, you're right, i didn't think about the print formatting.

Comment: I've added a generic print template function. If -Wformat is enabled, you will get some warnings. Either ignore them or disable -Wformat.